# Как вывести имя старшего пользователя из массива объектов? JS

Tags: javascript

помогите с пониманием темы, изучаю JS.
Прошу прощения что не написал решение , пробывал но не понимаю даже как начать

```js
let allUsers=[
  {
    name: 'Валя',
    age: 11
  },
  {
    name: 'Таня',
    age: 24
  },
  {
    name: 'Рома',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Надя',
    age: 34
  },
  {
    name: 'Антон',
    age: 7
  }
]

function getOlderUserArray(usersArray){
  // Здесь решение задачи




}

let result2 = getOlderUserArray(allUsers)
console.log('Старший пользователь:',result2);
```

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки. Возьмите бумажку и распишите для себя, как бы вы, как человек, решали бы эту задачу. Когда опишите, будет алгоритм, который надо перенести на код.мы поможем исправить ошибки

Comment: `allUsers.reduce(function(prev, current) { return (prev.age > current.age) ? prev : current }).name`

Answer (score -1):

```js
let allUsers=[
  {
    name: 'Валя',
    age: 11
  },
  {
    name: 'Таня',
    age: 24
  },
  {
    name: 'Рома',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Надя',
    age: 34
  },
  {
    name: 'Антон',
    age: 7
  }
]
function getOlderUserArray(usersArray){
  let arr = [];
  for(let i of usersArray){
    arr.push(i.age);
  }
  let obj = usersArray.filter( item => item.age >= Math.max(...arr))[0].name

  return obj;
}

console.log(getOlderUserArray(allUsers))
```